# The import com.android.datetimepicker cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've imported an existing Android project to Eclipse, but I'm getting errors on the following imports:

```
import com.android.datetimepicker.time.RadialPickerLayout;
import com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog;
```

I already have the `android-support-v4.jar` library added to the build path.
Could anybody help me to figure out what is missing?

Comment: I think you have the package wrong, there's an   android.app.TimePickerDialog

Comment: Well, I tried:
    import android.app.RadialPickerLayout;
    import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
But still getting import errors on these lines. :/

Comment: I would recommend clean and build the project and then try `import android.app.TimePickerDialog`

Comment: I tried that and it's still showing an importing error... Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of those classes exist in the Android SDK. There is a `TimePickerDialog`, as others have noted, in [a different package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html). There is a `RadialPickerLayout` in the [Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/+/android-4.3.1_r1/src/com/android/datetimepicker/time/RadialPickerLayout.java), and you are welcome to try to use it.

Really, you should be talking to whoever wrote this Android project and asking them where they were planning on getting those classes from.

Comment: Thank you!
Just downloaded it and imported to the project and it's now working. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the datetimepicker library where you have the package com.android.datetimepicker palced, please add the following to main project's build.gradle dependencies section:

```
compile project(':library')
```

This worked for me. Please let me know your comments.