# package com.android.datetimepicker.time does not exist?

Tags: android, android-source, android-alarms

When I cloned Android's default alarm in Anroid Open Source Project @ https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/ and tried to run it on Android Studio I got the following error:

```
package com.android.datetimepicker.time does not exist

cannot find symbol class TimePickerDialog

cannot find symbol class RadialPickerLayout <anonymous
com.android.deskclock.alarms.TimePickerCompat$TimerPickerPreL$1> is
not abstract and does not override abstract method
processTimeSet(int,int) in OnTimeSetListener
```

Please help in any way. Thank you.

Comment: post your gradle file code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The import com.android.datetimepicker cannot be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345424/the-import-com-android-datetimepicker-cannot-be-resolved)

Answer (score 1):

After a week of frustration, I was able to clone the default alarm app and get rid of the above DateTimePicker errors mentioned above by injecting the dependency to the gradle by:

compile 'com.github.citux:datetimepicker:0.2.0'

Thanks to the good people out there (https://github.com/CiTuX/datetimepicker) who have cloned and distributed as a gradle dependency of the framework used in Android Open Source Project @ https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker

Hope this will help some who works on cloned Android Open Source Project.

Answer (score -1):

> Neither of those classes exist in the Android SDK. There is a
>   TimePickerDialog, as others have noted, in a [different package.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html)
>   There is a RadialPickerLayout in the [Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/+/android-4.3.1_r1/src/com/android/datetimepicker/time/RadialPickerLayout.java), and you
>   are welcome to try to use it.
>
> Really, you should be talking to whoever wrote this Android project
>   and asking them where they were planning on getting those classes
>   from.

[Here is the main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345424/the-import-com-android-datetimepicker-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: Please don't just copy and paste another user's answer. If you think that post will answer this question, then vote this as a duplicate of that question. You have more than enough rep to cast that vote.

Comment: Yeah Vote for close tag @MikeM.

Comment: Thanks @ChintanKhetiya for pointing out they doesn't exist in Android SDK itself. That made me explore more inside the Android Source Code Project. I edited the question to add the url of the Android default alarm source code.